# Disable link when clicked on inside icon

Tags: html, css

I have some html that looks like this (pseudo, see real example below):

```
<a href="/someplace">
    <div>Some text</div>
    <div>
        <svg/> //icon here
    </div>
</a>
```

What I want is when I click on icon, nothing happens. But any other place should redirect on href in link. Is it possible to do so?

I tried z-index, but it didn't work

In the example click on yellow should redirect, but click on blue should not.

[Example](https://codepen.io/arturtakoev/pen/JjGqpZX)

Comment: #1: Invalid HTML. You can't have a block element inside an inline element. `<a>` is inline and it cannot contain a `<div>`, which is block.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Actually it's completely valid, assuming the invalid closing `<a/>` and unknown `<icon/>` tags were fixed or removed. I believe it was invalid prior to HTML5.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman, pls see the example, it's valid.

Comment: So put the icon outside the `a` element.

Comment: @ArturTakoev Sure...

Comment: @ArturTakoev It works on CodePen for me.

Comment: @Mobina real case it a bit more complicated, block with icon has to be inside. Also as you can see from example I need to be able to click on all of the yellow, so putting it outside will cause problems with positioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.icon` is a child of `.link`, the `pointer-events` style won't have an effect. You'll need to block any clicks in an `onclick` handler (e.g. `<div class="icon" onclick="return false;">`, or added via JavaScript).

You can also keep the cursor from changing when hovering the `.icon` element by adding a `cursor: default;` style to it.

Be aware that clicks on the `.icon` element will still trigger the `.link:active` styles.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: beige;
}

.link {
    z-index: 1;
}

.icon {
    width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  cursor: default;
}



body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3rem;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    transition: all 725ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a href="/none" class="link">
  <div class="container">
    <div>Text</div>
    <div class="icon" onclick="return false;">
      <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M10,1.375c-3.17,0-5.75,2.548-5.75,5.682c0,6.685,5.259,11.276,5.483,11.469c0.152,0.132,0.382,0.132,0.534,0c0.224-0.193,5.481-4.784,5.483-11.469C15.75,3.923,13.171,1.375,10,1.375 M10,17.653c-1.064-1.024-4.929-5.127-4.929-10.596c0-2.68,2.212-4.861,4.929-4.861s4.929,2.181,4.929,4.861C14.927,12.518,11.063,16.627,10,17.653 M10,3.839c-1.815,0-3.286,1.47-3.286,3.286s1.47,3.286,3.286,3.286s3.286-1.47,3.286-3.286S11.815,3.839,10,3.839 M10,9.589c-1.359,0-2.464-1.105-2.464-2.464S8.641,4.661,10,4.661s2.464,1.105,2.464,2.464S11.359,9.589,10,9.589"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>

</a>
```

Comment: thank you, in my case I also had to add preventDefault, but general case is working :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onclick=""`attribute for this. Check this. Update your code like this.

```js
yes_js_login = function(event) {
    alert("Hello World :) :) :) ");
    return false;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: beige;
}

.link {
    z-index: 1;
}

.icon {
    width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 9999;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}



body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3rem;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    transition: all 725ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" class="link">
  <div class="container">
    <div>Text</div>
    <div class="icon">
      <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20" onclick="return yes_js_login();">
        <path d="M10,1.375c-3.17,0-5.75,2.548-5.75,5.682c0,6.685,5.259,11.276,5.483,11.469c0.152,0.132,0.382,0.132,0.534,0c0.224-0.193,5.481-4.784,5.483-11.469C15.75,3.923,13.171,1.375,10,1.375 M10,17.653c-1.064-1.024-4.929-5.127-4.929-10.596c0-2.68,2.212-4.861,4.929-4.861s4.929,2.181,4.929,4.861C14.927,12.518,11.063,16.627,10,17.653 M10,3.839c-1.815,0-3.286,1.47-3.286,3.286s1.47,3.286,3.286,3.286s3.286-1.47,3.286-3.286S11.815,3.839,10,3.839 M10,9.589c-1.359,0-2.464-1.105-2.464-2.464S8.641,4.661,10,4.661s2.464,1.105,2.464,2.464S11.359,9.589,10,9.589"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>

</a>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/lahiru444/j0gbLqhw/1/)